# Implementing Queue API in Java Using Resizable Array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

```
package com.queueapi;

/**
 * Created by Dhaval on 6/15/2016.
 */

public class DynamicArrayQueue {
    private String[] s;
    private int head = -1;
    private int tail = -1;

    public DynamicArrayQueue() {
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == -1 || head > tail || s.length == 0;
    }

    public void enqueue(String item) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = 0;
            tail = 0;
            s = new String[1];
        }

        if (tail - head == s.length) {
            resize(s.length * 2);
        }

        s[tail++] = item;
    }

    public String dequeue() throws QueueUnderFlowException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new QueueUnderFlowException();
        }

        String item = s[head++];
        if (tail - head == s.length / 4) {
            resize(s.length / 2);
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void resize(int capacity) {
        String[] copy = new String[capacity];
        for (int i = head; i < tail; i++) {
            copy[i - head] = s[i];
        }
        s = copy;
        tail = tail - head;
        head = 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a dynamically resizable queue using arrays which supports three basic functionality:

1. `isEmpty()`
2. `Enqueue()`
3. `Dequeue()`

The constrains are that the queue should always be filled within 25-100% and therefore I am resizing the array to double its size when queue is full and reduce the size to size/2 if the number of elements in queue us equal to size/4.

This queue is used with a tester which takes the input as:
1 - 2 - 3 - where when "-" occurs dequue() operation takes place or else enqueue().

The code is failing on 1 2 3 - - - -  as input. Please provide me some insight on where I am going wrong.

Tester Client

```
package com.queueapi;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class QueueTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws QueueUnderFlowException {

        DynamicArrayQueue queue = new DynamicArrayQueue();
        while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){

            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if(s.equals("-")){
                StdOut.print(queue.dequeue());
            }
            else{
                queue.enqueue(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is failing"?

Comment: Well, I guess the expected output would be a `QueueUnderFlowException` - what output do you get?

Comment: Please post the tester class code, failing means any exception or unexpected behavior ?

Comment: Failing means that the particular test case is not throwing the exception which it should.

Comment: Did you debug your code in IDE, just step by step? Or did you print the queue state (head, tail, length) before and after each operation?

Comment: Yes I tried to debug it in my Intellij and the issue I get it prints 123null in the test case I mentioned. It is some kind of off by one error which I am not able to figure out exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem case, member values are:

```
head tail s
-1   -1   []
   Enque "1"
0    1    ["1"]
   Enque "2"
0    2    ["1" "2"]
   Enque "3"
0    3    ["1", "2", "3", null]
   Deque -> "1"
1    3    ["1", "2", "3", null]
   Deque -> "1"
0    1    ["3", null]
   Deque -> "1"
0    0    [null]
   Deque -> null
```

From this it becomes pretty clear.  You are not raising an "Underflow" because:

- head is not -1, nor
- head is not greater than tail, nor
- is the array length zero.

The number of items in the queue is `tail - head`, which is zero.   But you don't check that; instead you check `head > tail`, which would only fail if the number of items in the queue was negative.

You could fix this by testing `head >= tail`, instead.

Comment: Of course, this won't fix all your problems.   The next failure case will be: `1 2 3 - 4 5`.  Why?  Exercise left for student.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. Here is the bug fix in enqueue method for the case which failed earlier.

if(tail - head == s.length || tail > s.length - 1){
            resize(s.length * 2);
}